# Grant access to separate Data Lake Gen 2 folders for different users using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, automation, azure-powershell, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

Although I can grant access to different users in Azure Data Lake Gen 2 using [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-powershell#manage-access-permissions), I'd like to be able to grant access so that each user has access to their own separate folders with each Data Lake Gen 2 container e.g. Within Container 1, User A has access to sub folder A and User B has access to Sub Folder B. This is possible using the Storage explorer UI but I'm unable to do so using PowerShell commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the script below to give permission to the user.

In my sample, I have a container `test`, there are two folders, `folder1` and `folder2`. I give the `rwx` permission to the user in `folder1`.

```
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "xxxxx" -AccountName "joygen"
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

$filesystemName = "test"
$dirname = "folder1/"
$objectid = "<object-id of the user in Azure AD>"
$acl = New-AzDataLakeGen2ItemAclObject -AccessControlType user -EntityId $objectid -Permission rwx
Update-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $dirname -Acl $acl
```

After giving the permission, we can check with:

```
$dir = Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $dirname
$dir.ACL
```

[image]

For another user, just use the script to give permission to the `folder2`.

**Update:**

Yes, you can. Just use the script below, `$objectid1` and `$objectid2` are two users, `$objectid3` is an Azure AD security group. In the command, notice the usage of `-AccessControlType` and `-InputObject`.

```
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "xxxx" -AccountName "joygen"
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

$filesystemName = "test"
$dirname = "folder1/"
$objectid1 = "<object-id of the user1 in Azure AD>"
$objectid2 = "<object-id of the user2 in Azure AD>"
$objectid3 = "<object-id of the group in Azure AD>"
$acl = New-AzDataLakeGen2ItemAclObject -AccessControlType user -EntityId $objectid1 -Permission rwx
$acl = New-AzDataLakeGen2ItemAclObject -AccessControlType user -EntityId $objectid2 -Permission rwx -InputObject $acl
$acl = New-AzDataLakeGen2ItemAclObject -AccessControlType group -EntityId $objectid3 -Permission rwx -InputObject $acl
Update-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $dirname -Acl $acl
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to add more 2 or more users/groups to the folders instead of just one to each folder as the process shown by @Joy Wang appears to only allow for 1 user/group per separate folder?